# HashSet<T> quickly checking if identity exists by T.identity

Tags: c#, linq, containers, hashset

I have an entity called `Feature` which contains a value identity called `FeatureIdentity`.

I have a list of these entities, and i want to quickly determine if the identity already exists.

The kicker is i need to be able to compare by the FeatureIdentity and not be the Feature, the Contains procedure on lists is checking against a provided T parameter.

So I am currently doing the code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    HashSet<Feature> features = new HashSet<Feature>();

    public void SetRequirement(FeatureIdentity feature, FeatureIdentity requires)
    {
        if (ContainsFeature(feature) == false || ContainsFeature(requires) == false)
        {
            // throw
        }
        this.requirements.Add(feature, requires);
    }

    bool ContainsFeature(FeatureIdentity identity)
    {
        return this.features.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(identity)).Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

Does Linq optimize this, or is this there a correct optimal way of checking if the item exists?

```
public class Feature
{
   public Feature(FeatureIdentity id, string name)
   {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
   }

   FeatureIdentity id;
   string name;

   FeatureIdentity Id
   {
      get { return this.id; }
   }
}

public class FeatureIdentity : IEquatable<FeatureIdentity>
{
    private readonly string sku;

    public FeatureIdentity(string sku)
    {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public bool Equals(FeatureIdentity other)
    {
        return this.sku == other.sku;
    }

    public string Sku
    {
        get { return this.sku; }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.sku.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that a `HashSet<Feature>` instead of a `HashSet<FeatureIdentity>`?

Comment: Because i want to have a list of Features (that contains other attributes, such as name, and others that i have left out to make the example more concise). We just need to be able to determine quickly if an object is already in that list, based on its Identity

Comment: OK, so why a set of features instead of a list of features? You are not showing us what else you are doing with that collection, which is important. FYI, the existing implementation of `ContainsFeature` already causes the set to degenerate into a list, so it's not offering any benefit at all to the code we can see.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `HashSet<FeatureIdentity>`, possibly in addition to a `List<Feature>`, or alternatively, a `Dictionary<FeatureIdentity, Feature>`.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, there is a lot going on, too much to list, it's used as a list that gets added to. @Kris thanks, your sugestion of `Dictionary<FeatureIdentity, Feature>` seems like it would do the trick

Comment: @g18c: If it's used as a list then perhaps creating a custom equality comparer for the set that compares based on identity is the solution? That will allow you to do set-based operations on identity while leaving your list-based operations unaffected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with ctor `public HashSet()`, `HashSet<Feature>` is using `EqualityComparer<Feature>.Default` as default Comparer.

if you use `HashSet<Feature>,` you should implement `IEquatable<Feature>` and override `GetHashCode`.

```
public class Feature: IEquatable<Feature>
{
    public bool Equals(Feature other)
    {
        return this.id.Equals(other.id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

then you can try following workaround which waster a temp object from heap.

```
bool ContainsFeature(FeatureIdentity identity)
{
    return this.features.Contain(new Feature(identity, null));
}
```